# SARIMA: Determining the integration number

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, differencing

i am working with a time series that after calculating the first difference, it remains non-stationary. When plotting the series I see there is some seasonality at half and end of year. I would like to know how should i determine the parameters of the SARIMA(P,I,Q) model. Should i be looking at the ACF and PACF of the first difference of my series in order to determine P and Q, our should the ACF and PACF be for some adjustment of my series? Finally, i would really like to know how to determine the parameter I. Should i just run the SARIMA for I=0,1,2 and see what is best? In particular, when would I=0?

here is my series (after first difference):

[image]

I'll appreciate any guidence

Comment: This series clearly does not need differencing; there are no stochastic trends to take care of. Overdifferencing the series will double your error variance and yield a unit-root moving-average component -- not something you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I must add that this is the series after differentiating. My question is towards determining the parameters for the SARIMA model. specially the number of differentiations that must be done

Comment: Well, you clearly do not need to difference another time. Whether you needed to difference the original series or not remains an open question. Instead or at least in addition to posting the graph of the differenced series, you should post the graph of the original series.